# First Argument cannot be nil when trying to override Devise's Confirmations Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I'm trying to implement the override method outlined here [Devise- Override Confirmation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Override-confirmations-so-users-can-pick-their-own-passwords-as-part-of-confirmation-activation). My version of rails is 4 and ruby is 2.0. My implementation involves multiple resources, so i'm coding this override to a specific resource, a rider.

The show action is rendering correctly, and i can enter my password. But when i submit the form i get the following error message

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

I walked through the code with a debugger with watches for `@confirmable and self.resource` which are set in the `with_unconfirmed_confirmable and do_show` methods of the controller respectively, and it seems that while rendering the show template in the do_show method both @confirmable and self.resource are set to the user trying to confirm. However both are set to nil when updating the confirmation.

Since the code is rather long, i've put my controller, show template, and the devise related code in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/onthespotqa/7631577).

**EDIT in Response to the Comment**

I am storing the confirmation token in the form as a hidden field. It's set to the correct value (when i use it to query the db i get the user i expect).

Once again walking through it with a debugger, I noticed that the value of the confirmation token seems to be regenerated to a different toke during the update action, but it's correct in the request parameters.

```
{"rider"=>{"confirmation_token"=>"92f786e5270e3562aa48589cc6c36e083cc7a23a41bb55f92c338f381050ec8b"}, "commit"=>"Activate", "controller"=>"riders/confirmations", "action"=>"update"}
```

Because of that @confirmable is being set to nil.

So now i'm wondering why
    @confirmation_token = Devise.token_generator.digest(User, :confirmation_token, @original_token) generating a brand new token on update, when the value of @original_token seems to be the same (based on the watches in my debugger).

Comment: When you have a rendered show action, is there a hidden `confirmation_token` field in the form with a value? If, before submitting the form, you run the code that sets `@confirmable` by looking up the `User` by its token (lines 45 and 46 in your gist), do you get the `User` you expect? It sounds like something's going wrong with looking up the user by the token.

Comment: @carols10cents see my edits. i also updated the gist with some small changes i made.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working for the non-default user by setting the confirmation token in a hidden field using the hidden_field_tag instead of f.input. Doing this prevented the confirmation_token from being overwritten during the update. I've updated the gist to reflect the changes.